# htaccess rules html to php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to be able to redirect folders and subfolders (all html) to another server with different folders (php)

I have a domain with DNS redirects Cname and A field pointing the domiain (that has not changed) to new website using php.

So, I want to do the following as an example.

On the old server

http://www.domain.co.uk/folder1/subfolder1/page.html

to go to

New server

http://www.domain.co.uk/folder3/

The domain used to point at the htdocs folder on the first server but now using CNAME and an A field it points to the second (new) server

Can I just redirect bulk folders to the new folders?

Hope this makes sense

Richard

Comment: Canonical apache answer: [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect bulk folders.

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.otherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is a simple code that redirects ftm domain.com to otherdomain.com. But if you want to change folder1/folder2 to folder3, well.... just think you could you possibly shrink that to a simple rule? I think below 50 pages you better off wiriting 301 redirects line by line. Otherwise, no short way.

Comment: Hi, the domains are the same.
My ISP provided some webspace and the domain name use to point to this space and find the .html files under a /htdocs folder. As I am now using WP, my ISP has set the CNAME and A field to direct the domain name to a different server using CGI.
If too complicated, can you give me an example of how to do it long hand:
Would it be:
Redirect 301 /folder/name.html http://www.domain.co.uk/folder2
If this is the case, and I have tried it, the file found on google, for example name.html appears at the end of the redirect but the new server using php not html, thanks

Comment: Yes, the longhnad would be. Redirect 301 /folder/name.html domain.co.uk/folder2 I don't understand your point with php and html. Could you rephrase it please?